# In the MCU if you lift Mjolnir do you get Thor level strength?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, thor-2011

In *Thor* (2011) Odin says

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.

Then in *Avengers: Endgame* Captain America lifts the hammer. And we see him he can call it back or calls lightning bolts with it. How about getting Thor's strength?

Did Captain America get Thor-level strength after lifting Mjolnir?

Comment: Why wouldn't he? If he gets some powers why wouldn't he get them all? (Also I thought this was a dupe but my search is failing me).

Comment: I'm practically sure someone asked a similar question. At least, I remember reading something about this... Unless it wasn't specific to the MCU.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think he should, but we dont see him flying for example. BTW, I also thought someone probably asked this question, but when I looked in the search nothing appeared. Also I tried searching for mjolnir and I couldnt find anything